# Determine compatibility of function parameters at runtime in Haskell

Tags: haskell, introspection

Say I have a function f1 :: a -> b -> ... -> c and another function f2 :: PossibleTypeClass x y ... => x -> y -> ... -> z, I want to determine at runtime if c (output of f1) can be passed in to f2 as x or y or any other input.

I do have some control over the source, so if there is a way to generate metadata (template haskell, maybe?) for use at runtime, that would be fine.

In other words...

I have a number of functions (maybe think arrow-like, computation things, may be stateful) that have a set of inputs and outputs. I want to know which inputs are able to hook up with which outputs so the user can tie them together. Once that happens, we can generate code (or something like that) based on how the user configured them.

The functions I have I either wrote myself, or users can write them as well, so I might get them in compiled form. But I could require certain things in their code to generate metadata (if necessary) if it was very simple.

The biggest challenge is with type classes--how to find out whether the concrete type of an output is an instance of a type class of an input.

Comment: Doing this kind of thing at runtime in Haskell seems fishy. Isn't the purpose of the sofisticated type system to allow you to do this at compile time?

Comment: Sure, but what if compile time comes after runtime? I'm building something that allows the user to configure components that are then composed and executed together. I need to know what components can be plugged into each other based on their type signatures. Put another way, I need to know at runtime how to generate a type-safe, compilable program.

Comment: So you need something, that represents a Haskell type as an ADT? You don't want to analyze the code of the program itself, but rather the code of another program, that isn't compiled yet? Maybe I didn't understood your problem.

Comment: Added more clarification in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, what you want is possible with the module `Data.Dynamic`. It provides an algebraic data type `Dynamic` to do dynamic programming. The module is save to use, though you may only use monomorphic types.

Comment: How is that going to provide information about type compatibility at runtime?

Comment: @taotree: You can use `dynApply`. It returns the applied value if application is possible, and `Nothing` otherwise.

Comment: I think the restriction to monomorphic is going to be an issue, since it's type classes that are what I'm trying to solve. The concrete type case is rather straightforward. But dealing with matching a concrete output type with possibly just a type class constrained input... that's the challenge.

Comment: Maybe *Typing Haskell in Haskell* is what you're looking for. (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/thih) This package provides Anything you need to typecheck Haskell code in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment on your question, I guess what you are after is something like GHC API or hint. Both are ways to access some AST representation of code you just compiled. GHCi is based on GHC API and hint is a nice wrapper around GHC API.